# what is a "Valid System process" for mac and windows. (java ProcessBuilder)

Tags: java, windows, macos

I am trying to work out the semantics of using Java ProcessBuilder to call operating system processes and read this line out of the [javadocs for the start command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29):

> "This method checks that the command is a valid operating system command. Which commands are valid is system-dependent, but at the very least the command must be a non-empty list of non-null strings."

Tell me, What is considered a valid process for Mac and for Windows? Is it anything that can be found on the PATH variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it anything that can be found on the PATH variable?

Yes it is; although you can also specify the full path of the command if you like (such as `"/bin/ls"`). Another test if of course to check if the file in question is a regular file and has execution permissions.

Note: this will launch a "real" process, it *will not* launch it via a command interpreter; as such don't attempt to use pipes, file globs, shell builtins etc: those are interpreted by `sh`/`cmd`.

Comment: That being said, I could still invoke the cmd / sh with parameters if i wanted to have my command interpreted right? i.e. `new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/K", "process1", "arg1","arg2", "etc")`

Comment: Yes you could. Although I know of few scenarios where you actually need that. What does `/K` does?

Comment: I believe it runs the command provided and then remains. I was actually thinking of cmd /C which carries out the command then terminates.

Comment: Yes, `/C` looks better ;) Although don't forget that if you use a command interpreter you have far less control over what std{in,out,err} are.